# PHP - How can I apply an arbitrary filter to leaf nodes of hierarchical array?

Tags: php, arrays, filter

I'd like to be able to filter the leaf nodes of an array to make sure that data is formatted properly by any arbitrary specification.  Is there a simple way of applying a filtering function to the leaf nodes of a multidimensional array in PHP?

Comment: Is it a leaf node, or a lead node?

Comment: Sorry, I meant leaf node. I corrected the typo.

Comment: Do you mean a random filter or an arbitrary filter?

Comment: Arbitrary.  Updated title to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

```
function filter_leaf_nodes($tree, $filter) {
    $ret = array();
    foreach ($tree as $subtree) {
        if (is_array($subtree)) {
            $ret[] = filter_leaf_nodes($subtree, $filter);
        } else if ($filter($subtree)) {
            $ret[] = $subtree;
        }
    }
    return $ret;
}

$tree = array(
    array(
        array(
            -1,
            5
        ),
        -3,
        2,
    ),
    array(
        3,
        9
    ),
    -9
);

$filter = function($node) {
    return $node >= 0;
};

var_dump(filter_leaf_nodes($tree, $filter));
```